# reactive expressions and actionButton in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

In the shiny code shown below, the output is refreshed (random number changes) every time the button is clicked, irrespective of whether or not the input text changes.  How can this be written so that the output is refreshed only when the button is clicked AND the input is different?

```
require(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(
    navbarPage("Test",
        tabPanel("Panel1",
            fluidRow(
                column(offset=2, width=2,
                    textInput("text", label=h6("Input"), value="test123"),
                    br(),
                    actionButton("actionClick", label="Click")
                ),
                column(offset=1, width=2,
                    h6("Output"),
                    verbatimTextOutput(outputId="sessionId")
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    session <- reactive({
        input$actionClick

        isolate({
            return(input$text)
        })
    })

    output$sessionId <- renderText({paste(session(),runif(1))})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be solved by using cache variables:

```
require(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(
    navbarPage("Test",
        tabPanel("Panel1",
            fluidRow(
                column(offset=2, width=2,
                    textInput("text", label=h6("Input"), value="test123"),
                    br(),
                    actionButton("actionClick", label="Click")
                ),
                column(offset=1, width=2,
                    h6("Output"),
                    verbatimTextOutput(outputId="sessionId")
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    cacheText <- "NULL"
    cacheNumber <- "0"
    session <- reactive({
        input$actionClick

        isolate({
            return(input$text)
        })
    })

    output$sessionId <- renderText({

        if(cacheText != session()) {
            cacheText <<- input$text
            cacheNumber <<- runif(1)
            return(paste(session(),cacheNumber))


        } else {
            return(paste(cacheText, cacheNumber))
        }



    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```